# cannot initialize object parameter for "some widgets" with an expression type 'MainWindow'が起きるのはどうしてなのでしょうか。

Tags: c++, windows-10, qt, c++11, qt-creator

`QtCreator 4.7` `Qt5.11`で`mainwindow`プロジェクトを立ち上げました。

`pro`ファイルと、`h`ファイル、そして`cpp`ファイルの３つが自動で出来上がるのですけれども、意味不明なエラーが出ます。
**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show(); 
    return a.exec();
}
```

**出現エラー**

> cannot initialize object parameter of type 'QWidget' with an
>   expression type 'MainWindow'

プロジェクトを立ち上げていただいて、全く改編をしていない初期状態のコードです。
qt creator 4.7をインストールされてらっしゃる方はすぐに作れる状態です。一応タイトルが似た質問を見付けましたが[Cannot initialize return object of type 'int' with an lvalue of type 'cocos2d::Scene *'](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14892/cannot-initialize-return-object-of-type-int-with-an-lvalue-of-type-cocos2ds)は、cocoa2d-xのもので、qtではありませんでした。

一応他のコードも載せます。
**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~MainWindow();
    };

    #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.pro**

```
        #-------------------------------------------------
    #
    # Project created by QtCreator 2018-09-14T16:52:20
    #
    #-------------------------------------------------

    QT       += core gui widgets

    TARGET = MainWindow
    TEMPLATE = app

    # The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
    # any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
    # depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
    # deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
    DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

    # You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
    # In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
    # You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
    #DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

    CONFIG += c++11

    SOURCES += \
            main.cpp \
            mainwindow.cpp

    HEADERS += \
            mainwindow.h

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**追記：**
問題が起きない方の環境だと、こうなります。
qt 5.9.6
qt-creator 4.7.0
他は同じ。

ただし、コンパイラが、msvc2017であるのに対して、問題が起きるほうは、
min-GW32が選ばれ、これは、`32bit`と書いてあります。おそらく、コンパイラ
のセットが不十分であるために起るバグだろうと考えていますが、推測の域を出ません。
インストール時に特に変わった設定はしていないつもりなのですが、なぜかこうなりました。

---

**実行環境**

Windows 10
64bit
qt-creator 4.7
c++11
qt 5.11

Comment: `mainwindow.pro`の内容が誤っているように見受けます。訂正されたほうがよいと思います。

Comment: @user20098 申し訳ありません。貼り間違えです。わけあってすぐに更新できませんが、一応連絡だけしておきたいと思います。

Comment: `QtCreator`4.7だと、コンパイル前にコード解析が動作すると思いますが、質問のエラーはコード解析で出ますか? あるいはコンパイル時に出ますか?

Comment: @user20098 はい。私は少しその辺が分らないのですが、いつもリビルドとかを適当に操作しています。デバッグで実行も押します。エラーというと違うかもしれません。エディタ上に警告のような形で出てきます。右側に赤い文字です。

Answer (score 1):

`QtCreator`4.7だと、デフォルトで「コード解析」が自動実行されるようです。
これが指摘するエラーについては、実際にコンパイルできるのであれば、無視してよいかと思います。

＃コンパイルが成功した後、再度コード解析を実行させるとエラーが消えると思います。
＃UIファイルがあるプロジェクトを生成した場合、UIファイルから自動生成されるソースコードが生成される前にコード解析が実行されることがあり、エラーと判断されることがあるようです。

Comment: `Qt Creator`を立ち上げますと、`Windows Runtime デバイスを検出しています。
C:/Qt/5.11.1/winrt_armv7_msvc2015/bin/winrtrunner.exe --list-devices
C and C++ compiler paths differ. C compiler may not work.
C and C++ compiler paths differ. C compiler may not work.
1 個の Windows Runtime デバイスが見つかりました。`と出てきます。一応書いておきたいと思います。

Comment: ご指摘の通り`pro`ファイルを修正いたしました。回答をいただけてたことに気づいておりませんで、もう少しお時間下さい。最後の策として、5.9.6をインストールしてやろうかなと考えたりしています。（これが一番うまくいってましたので。）きっかけはあほでして、5.11が最新だと思っていなかったからです。

Comment: 何故かわかりませんが、今度はこのようなエラーが出ました。`:-1: エラー: cannot open C:\Users\　　~1\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.7676.15.jom for write`おっしゃる通り赤文字エラーは消えています。（日にちが変われば起きる事も変わっているように私には感じられてしまい、少し混乱しています。）